# jQuery Ui Droppable Drop location issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to use the droppable plugin for my site.  I have a footer dock that have items in a ul list and I am trying to be able to drag items out of the footer dock into any where BUT the dock to remove the item.  However no matter what I've tried, it doesn't work as expected.  It will allow me to drop it anywhere and it will be removed.

here is my sample code:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
...
<div id="page">
...
<div id="dock">
     <ul>
          <li class="item">item 1</li>
          <li class="item">item 2</li>
     </ul>
</div>
...
</div>
...
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
$("body").droppable({
     accept: ".item",
     drop: function(event, ui) {
          removeItem();
     }
});

$(".item").draggable({
     helper: "clone"
});
```

So the above code doesn't do what I was expecting.  I am able to remove the items even when I am still in the dock.  So I can drag the item for like a couple pixels and let go and it would remove the item.  What I want is have it able to drop anywhere BUT the dock area to remove.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making your dock draggable with option `greedy: true` and reverting the item when dropped upon: http://jsfiddle.net/SKDDZ/

Comment: Hello, thanks for the solution and it works however I thought there was a more elegant way to do it via the api.  Because your solution would mean I have to create two droppables on the same element because I am allowing items to be drop into the dock as well which I didn't illustrate.  If there are no way to do this in the API, then your solution would probably be the best alternative.  Strange we can't say $("body").not("#dock").droppable()....but thank you for a good solution...